# Sending e-mail on behalf of another e-mail address for a client

Tags: email

I am in quite a bit of a bind here.  My boss and one of our higher profile clients are asking me to set up an e-mail blast of about 75 recipients, but they want it to come from the client.  Apparently, we used to do this all the time for the client.  Someone who used to work here would send the email blasts from Outlook and she was able to send them on behalf of client@xyz.com.  Now I've looked into how to do this, but if I change the From in Outlook, i'll get a bounce back saying I don't have authorization to send on behalf of that person.  Both my boss and the client insist that the client did not have to do anything to verify or authorize this, and we were just able to do it.  Whoever the IT guy was many years ago somehow was able to set things up so we could email on behalf of client@xyz.com and their IT dept didnt even have to get involved.

Here's the problem: I've tried to explain to both my boss and the client that the email wont go out unless their IT dept goes and does something to authorize me from an outside domain to email on behalf of the client. This makes sense to me... otherwise anyone could just send emails as anybody they want, right?  But, both of them are older and very stubborn and say "you guys used to be able to do this for us, why can't you now?" and I just look like I don't know what I'm doing.  The client refuses to go to his IT dept because it would take over a week for them to do anything (they are a big corporation, so everything is opened with a ticket, assigned to someone, etc.).  I simply need to send a pre-written email to about 75 of their stations on behalf of client@xyz.com, but bypassing authorization.

I don't know how mailchimp gets authorization to do this...I looked into mailchimp, and told the client he could verify us that way if he didn't want to get his IT department involved.  The client got mad cause it wanted him to register for mailchimp to verify.

This is what I do know: back when we did this, our company had its own e-mail server, and I remember it didn't use SSL.  I'm wondering if this is how whoever the IT guy was was able to set this up?  We use Office 365 now.  I don't know much at all about how to set up an e-mail server.

Is there a way to send an email on behalf of someone without having to get authorization?  I don't want to be responsible for losing this client and possibly lose my job over this stupid e-mail list.

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 will not be allowing you to send on behalf of a 3rd party address.

To do what they want, you will need an email server.  The problem is that many of the emails will not get delivered since they will not originate from the proper email server(s) for the client and will be flagged as spam.

To make this work, you will need that email server, and the client IT department will have to make DNS changes to make your server an authorized source of email from their domain.

Or just set up a quick ubuntu server with postfix configured as the MTA for the client and send the blast.  Some (or most) won't get delivered though.